# PHPStorm7 "Failed to create JVM: error code -4" on startup

Tags: java, php, intellij-idea, jvm, phpstorm

So today I tried to run my PHPStorm7 IDE and I got this error :

[image: Imgur]

I get a "Failed to create JVM error"; how can I avoid it?

I found [this related issue](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793), but it didn't help me.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393413-The-JVM-could-not-be-started-The-main-method-may-have-thrown-an-exception

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So i just fixed my problem thanks to @lena :

Edit the **Phpstorm.exe.vmoptions** file (IDE_HOME\bin\Phpstorm.exe.vmoptions) :

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
```

And reduce -Xmx value step by step reducing by 100m every time until it starts.

Comment: That's a crazy solution but it worked for me. I got it load by changing the -Xmx to 924m; down from 1024m.

Comment: For people that use 64 bit version, please see my answer below. Actually you don't need all these modifications.

Comment: The error came up just after i set this value via dialog to 1024 in my setup. I ended up resetting the value to it's default, which was 512 in my case and it works again.

Answer (score 5):

This is JVM problem; Oracle JVM requires a single chunk of continuous memory (more or less equal to the sum of Xmx and XX:MaxPermSize parameters values) to initialize. On Windows systems 32-bit java can only allocate up to 1.5 Gb. And any libraries that inject themselves into process memory will reduce this solid block.

You can try to cleanup your system and uninstall/disable as many of such autoloading stuff as possible (context menu extensions, residental programs that can intercept global keys (e.g. Translator/Dictionary, IM, fraps, some graphic drivers have "hot keys" etc etc). The PhpStorm.exe launcher can itself cause additional fragmentation, thus I'd suggest using PhpStorm.bat instead.

see also https://jetbrains.zendesk.com/entries/23393413 for some hints

Answer (score 3):

Probably you were using 64bit version as me, if so change the shortcut launcher from `{path}\PhpStorm.exe` to `{path}\PhpStorm64.exe`

This worked for me without any other trick.

Comment: For some reason I got an error saying it was running low on memory so I increased the RAM requirements on all then i got the error above, changing the path to PhpStorm64.exe fixed this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating my computer (Ubuntu), I solve this issue by removing the line -XX:MaxPermSize=350m